# Creating a web-based code editor

Tags: php, content-management-system, editor

I'm looking into creating a web-based code editor pane on my CMS. I would want something very similar to what Wordpress has if you go under the templates and edit individual .css or .php files. Are there easy plugins for this?

Security is not a HUGE issue, as this is a closed system, and the people using my CMS to manipulate the .php code etc. would only hurt themselves if they broke anything or injected code there.

So I want to get an idea of how I can accomplish this - write my own? Plug-ins that display file contents in an easy format?

Comment: Yes but if someone else gained access, they could cripple the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Code Mirror](http://codemirror.net/) will get you the basic features/behavior of an IDE in a variety of languages. I use it for a simple query editor in one of my applications. They have a [PHP](http://codemirror.net/mode/php/index.html) plugin available and you can write/modify your own.

Keep in mind that you should sanitize any input that is coming from an untrusted source. Even if your system is "closed loop" you may want to run user-provided code in a sandbox or have it undergo some sort of approval workflow.

There is also [Compilr](http://compilr.com/), but I don't know how well that integrates into a custom application.

Comment: Doing my round of answer clean ups - sorry it took so long to give you the points! Thanks for your help, I always appreciate it very much.